# heroku deploy: ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.staticfiles'

Tags: django, heroku

I am deploying my app to heroku. I stuck at this code:

```
$ heroku run python mysite/manage.py migrate
```

**The output are:**

```
Running `python mysite/manage.py migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.8367
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/mysite/django/apps/config.py", line 118, in create
    cls = getattr(mod, cls_name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'staticfiles'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysite/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/mysite/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_fr
om_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/mysite/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/app/mysite/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/mysite/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/app/mysite/django/apps/config.py", line 123, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.3/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in im
port_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1529, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.staticfiles'
```

Could anyone helps me with that? I searched a lot on staticfiles, but it does not work...

Comment: Need some more info, like which version of Django, for starters

Comment: >>> django.VERSION
(1, 7, 8, 'final, 0')

Comment: Could you show your settings file? INSTALLED_APPS section

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that your `staticfiles` contrib is installed via:

```
pip install django-staticfiles
```

<sup>Note: If `pip` points to your Python 2 instance, then use `pip3` instead.</sup>

Then verify your `PYTHONPATH` if it has the correct paths.